# regex for custom name validation -emptyspace, ', - only once

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex that has some custom rules. Im not good with regex, so here are some rules I am trying out :

1. No Whitespaces
2. Only one space between words allowed
3. No special characters except apostrophe (`'`) and hyphen (`-`) and only one which is within the words like O'Brian

Examples

```
John Gray Brian
John Brian
John O'Brian
John O-Brian
```

Comment: Rule #1 is "no whitespaces". Rule #2 says "one space". Which is it? Also, your examples are all strung together; could you list them separately so we can tell one from the next?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex (see [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/dY0gZ1/3)) with the 'i' flag:

`^[a-z]+([-'][a-z]+)?( [a-z]+([-'][a-z]+)?)*$`

Breakdown:

`^[a-z]+` start with any amount of letters

`([-'][a-z]+)?` possibly match a dash or apostrophe followed by more letters

`( [a-z]+([-'][a-z]+)?)*$` match any amount of other names, each preceded by one space, up to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var r = /^\w+(?:['-]\w*)?(?: \w+(?:['-]\w*)?)+$/;
r.test("John Gray")
// Result: true

r.test("    ")
// Result: false

r.test("John O'Brian")
// Result: true

r.test("John O-Brian")
// Result: true

r.test("John  O-Brian")
// Result: false
```

I recommend you learn how this works by researching JavaScript regex; that way you can learn it. ;)  [Try starting here.](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript)